# Using part of a struct within a select statement

Tags: sql, struct, google-bigquery

I am trying to pull part of a Struct into my query from my table its set up like below. Does anyone know how to do this?

Customers

--Id

--Identifier

I tried customer.id but I know I need to use the Struct function just having trouble getting it right

Comment: Does [this info](https://hevodata.com/learn/bigquery-structs/#qgs) possibly help?

Comment: your description is not 100% clear, but see if following helps: select customer.id from (
select struct(1 as id, 'xyz' as identifier) as customer
union all
select struct(2 as id, 'abc' as identifier) as customer
)